# After Blender is done installing, why doesn't it open?

Tags: windows, installation

After I install Blender.exe and click "Finish" nothing happens. In the YouTube tutorials I have watched, everyone has had a cmd looking thing that pops up and then runs Blender.

Comment: Hello... you mean Blender is not automatically started by the installer or do you mean it does not run at all when launch by its icon ?

Comment: *"a cmd looking thing that pops up"* — you mean the Start menu?

Comment: "a cmd looking thing that pops up" - I bet he means Blender console. Anyway, if Blender doesn't start from the installer alone, then start it manually from the start menu, or the desktop icon if you have one. It's not the installer's job to launch an application for you.

Comment: I had a similar problem once when I updated to a newer blender version. The shortcut wasn't working for me anymore. just deleted it and made a new shortcut referring to the new blender.exe.
Another possible reason is you might not have administrator rights (just a thought)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to click your start menu, the Windows icon located in the bottom left corner, then select "All Programs" and Blender should be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Find the file in the blender folder called `blender.exe` double click it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34120)

Comment: How is this not an answer to the question? @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, reading the question, the user likely clicked the wrong exe, or just didn't open the exe at all.

Comment: Sorry, it's automated message from the system. I meant that this should be posted as a comment instead